# Undefined control sequence!?

Tags: biblatex

I'm new to LaTEX.
My document was compiling completely fine. I added \usepackage{biblatex}, compiling failed. So deleted the biblatex package and tried again, but now my compiling failed again. I don't know whats happened, surely if my text was exactly the same as before it should run?

Here is my pre-document

```
 \documentclass[12pt]{article}
```

Here is my document. If it helps.

```
begin{document}

\begin{titlepage}

\newcommand{\HRule}{\rule{\linewidth}{0.5mm}}
\center
\textsc{\LARGE University of Manchester}\\[1.5cm]
\textsc{\Large School of Mathematics}\\[0.5cm]
\textsc{\large MMath Project}\\[0.5cm]
\textsc{\large MATH$40000$}\\[0.5cm]

\HRule \\[0.5cm]
{ \huge \bfseries Soft Tissues }\\[0.4cm]
\HRule \\[1.5cm]

\begin{minipage}{0.4\textwidth}
\begin{flushleft} \large
\emph{Author:}\\
Billy \textsc{Cole}
\end{flushleft}
\end{minipage}
~
\begin{minipage}{0.4\textwidth}
\begin{flushright} \large
\emph{Supervisor:} \\
Dr. William Parnell
\end{flushright}
\end{minipage}\\[2cm]


{\large \today}\\[2cm]
\vfill

\end{titlepage}


\tableofcontents
\clearpage

\begin{abstract}
   abstract-text
\end{abstract}
\clearpage


\section{The Biology of Collagen}

\subsection{Collagen}
% PARAGRAPH
% intro to the abundance and importance within the body?
% into to, what actually is collagen?
% why is it in this thesis?

% PARAGRAPH
% more specific molecular structure of collagen.
% why this molecular structure makes it strong.

% PARAGRAPH
% hierarchy structure of collagen
% why this hierarchy structure makes it strong.
% include anisotropic properties.
% include

% PARAGRAPH
%

\subsection{Other Types of Tissue that Need to be Noted}

\subsection{How Collagen Works on the Chosen Soft Tissue}

% PARAGRAPH
% definitions of stress and strain
% and why

\subsection{Modelling Soft Tissues}

% PARAGRAPH
% the process of mathematical modelling

% PARAGRAPH
% intro to Linear Elasticity
% intro to Non linear Elasticity
% intro to Visoelasticity

\subsection{Extra Chapter}
% maybe on the ageing of collagen.

\clearpage
\section{The Mathematics}

\clearpage
\section{Modelling}

\clearpage
\section{Conclusion}

\clearpage
\section{Appendix}

\clearpage
\section{Bibliography}
%\begin{thebibliography}
%
%%\bibitem[lable]{marker}
%
%\end{thebibliography}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome, horrible template for the title page. Better use the one from Wikibooks: https://en.wikibooks.org/w/index.php?title=LaTeX/Title_Creation&stable=0

Comment: A compilable document would be better to reproduce your error though i guess deleting the auxiliary files will do the job.

Comment: @Johannes_B, Cheers that worked, not sure why, but thank-you.

Comment: LaTeX writes information to auxiliary files that are read the next compile run. Sometimes, they need to be deleted to properly work again. It happens.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because there was some dodgy stuff in an auxiliary file.